# how to remove spaces between three buttons

Tags: android, xml

i added three buttons to bottom in my xml layout, and i want to remove spaces between these three buttons.

**this is my layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**it looks like this:**

http://s29.postimg.org/quhm1clzb/image.png

**but i want it to look like this in every screen size**

http://s29.postimg.org/deulbwdhj/image.png

Comment: Use LinearLayout and set their weight to 1 for all buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick the buttons in a horizontal `LinearLayout` and set the `layout_weight` to 1 for each button and set their `width` to 0dp. And for the `LinearLayout` just set the `align_parentBottom` to true. Should do it for you.

I just ripped this straight from one of my projects, so the names and things are a bit different, but it's essentially the same thing.

E.g.

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/ohsblue">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@anim/button_click"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="@color/headerText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/submitQuestionnaireButton"/>   
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@anim/button_click"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textColor="@color/headerText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/deleteQuestionnaireButton"/>       
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@anim/button_click"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/headerText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/cancelQuestionnaireButton"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: even after this small space is left between each button. Right?

Comment: Nope, should fill it completely. I have padding in mine, but that doesn't affect the spacing between them. I use custom-made buttons with  a little line between them in mine so it matches the colour's background.

Answer (score 0):

Use a linear layout-with a horizontal orientation- for the buttons. Do evaluate the changes that affect the width of the button if the text of the button changes.

Your resultant layout would be:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This will not work. You need to set the width to 0dp else it'll just wrap them as normal and take precedence over the weight.

Comment: @Gentatsu thanks, didn't check the layout_width attribute. Would apply in your example too :)

Answer (score 0):

use `LinearLayout` for making same size `Button`

try this..

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"    
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*Try this code:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_toLeftOf and layout_toRightOf.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/view_pager"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01"
   android:text="test"
 /> 

<Button
  android:id="@+id/Button01"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:text="test"
 />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/Button02"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button01"
   android:text="test"/>
```